# login with facebook or google+

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, google-plus, google-plus-signin

Just curious,

In case I want to make application using API for login(i.e Facebook of Google+)

1. What user's unique key do I stored in my database? Do my apps have same user's unique key as them(Facebook or google+), or they generate a new unique key for my user when sign in my apps? And what type of data is it?
2. Do I duplicate user's information into my database or keep accessing user's information from Facebook or Google+? Like do I have to create table for user's name, gender, birthday,etc and register user's information once user login to my apps or straight access it from Facebook or Google+ every time my apps needs it?
3. Is it really safe for user to using login with API? Can someone using API to get user's email and password, or make post in user's Facebook or Google+ that user don't want to post, or hijack user's account?

This might be common case, but I have no experience in using API so I have no idea about that.

Comment: Its all upto your Implementation. In some application it treats different user but if you want to restrict and treat like same user then you need to check some entity is same or not ,like if you are normally login and after that want to login by using gmail or facebook  so first check whether the email id is same or not if same then you can update the same existing user and return the same user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What user's unique key do I stored in my database? Do my apps have same user's unique key as them(Facebook or google+), or they generate a new unique key for my user when sign in my apps? And what type of data is it?

When you use Google or Facbook *signin* you really only need to store the information that they return to you.

```
LoginProvider   ProviderKey         ProviderDisplayName      UserId
_____________________________________________________________________
Facebook        1969950809700159        Facebook             21248583
Google          117200475532672775346   Google               21248582
```

User Id is the users id from my user table.  Where i store there user information my system needs ProviderKey is the users Id on the login providers system.

> Do I duplicate user's information into my database or keep accessing user's information from Facebook or Google+? Like do I have to create table for user's name, gender, birthday,etc and register user's information once user login to my apps or straight access it from Facebook or Google+ every time my apps needs it?

You can duplicate some of it when the user creates or links their account to your system but i wouldn't automatically update it without informing the user you are doing so.  Some users dont realize how much information you have access to via linking to social media accounts.

> Is it really safe for user to using login with API? Can someone using API to get user's email and password, or make post in user's Facebook or Google+ that user don't want to post, or hijack user's account?

I think you are confusing identity for Authentication.   Using Oauth2 you request a user to grant you access to see there data though an api this is authorization.   If you are using Google+ or facebook signin you are using an identity server and signing in as the user.  You should be using signin if you want them to login to your system using their social media accounts.   By singing in you are that user.  No I dont think they can be hijacked using signin.